# Can PyMySQL be used as a drop-in replacement of MySQL/Connector for Python?

Tags: mysql, pymysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm looking for a replacement of MySQL/Connector for Python and was wondering if PyMySQL can be used as a direct replacement. If I go that way should I expect some different output formatting of the output. For it I run a SELECT query on table that contains text, numbers and date/time fields, would  PyMySQL return the output formatted in the same way as MySQL/Connector?
Also should I expect any issues running other type of queries like INSERT , DELETE etc.

I'd appreciate if you share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```py
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb
```

Now you can use `pymysql` as `MySQLdb`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, there are no other answers, I'm going to share my experience so far. 
I can say PyMySQL works fine as a replacement of MySQL/Connector for Python. The query outputs are compatible and I had no issues updating the tables. 
One thing that is worth noting is the slightly different error output. I didn't find much about error handling in PyMySQL documentation. Generally it returns a tuple consisting of the error number and error message. It looks slightly different than MySQL/Connector's error output, so one should be careful when capturing them.
Also the list of .connect() arguments is different but these are well documented.

Hope that may be helpful.